# Is it needed to use local DNS cacher in EC2 / VPC?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dig, amazon-vpc

Seems like AWS internal DNS is already a very low latency one, e.g.

On ec2

```
dig google.com |  grep "Query time"
;; Query time: 0 msec
```

So do we really need to use another DNS cacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the answer to yourselv if you take a look at your nscd stats.